# Jquery each loop $this pointer scope

Tags: jquery, reactjs, each

In jQuery I'm stuck with understanding `this` scope inside an `each` loop. I'm not able to access other function accessing inside each loop.

I'm getting this error:

> self.loadGraphChart is not function" and "Cannot read property 'location' of undefined

Please do let me know how can I access other functions inside each loop.

```
    loadGraphOnScroll() {         
      var self = this;

      $(".scrollPosition").each(function() {
        var cluster = self.props.location.query.id;
        self.loadGraphChart('p1','p2');
      }
    });
  }

  loadGraphChart('p1','p2') {
}
```

**Edit**

Actual code from comments:

```
loadGraphOnScroll() { 
  $(".scrollPosition").each(function() { 
    var visible = $(this).visible('partial'); 
    if(visible == true) { 
      var getId = $(this).attr('id'); 
      var id = this.props.location.query.id; 
      var graphType = jsonData.plots[getId].graphType;
      this.loadGraphChart(id, graphType); 
    } 
  }); 
}
```

Comment: The question you should be asking is, what's "this" *outside* the loop?  The loop is a red-herring.   How are you calling 'loadGraphOnScroll' ?

Comment: If, within the loop, you want to access each `.scrollPosition` - then get rid of the `self=this` and just use `this` inside the loop:  `var cluster = this.props...  ; this.loadGraph...`

Comment: Or put `var self = this` *inside* the `.each`

Comment: here is my actual code :

Comment: loadGraphOnScroll() {

    $(".scrollPosition").each(function() {

        var visible = $(this).visible('partial'); 
        if(visible == true) {

            var getId = $(this).attr('id');

            var id = this.props.location.query.id;
            var graphType = jsonData.plots[getId].graphType;

            this.loadGraphChart(id, graphType);
        }

    });
}

Comment: As u said, I was using this.props and this.loadGraph but getting same error as above..

Comment: I guess there is conflict between $(this) and this

Comment: Your issue is with `.props` not this/$this.  `this` is an html element, which doesn't have property "props"  `$(this)` is a jquery wrapper around the html element.  Perhaps it's a "react.js" thing that I'm unaware of.

Comment: If you provide some html for one of the `.scrollPosition` elements, along with its attributes, we can possibly help further.